# How to assign a unique user id in my android application?

Tags: android

I am creating a user based android application wherein each user will be registered with a unique id when he/she will be signing up for the first time. How do I do it?

Comment: register with device unique id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Answer (score 1):

For Device id

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: It's known to be null sometimes, it's documented as "can change upon factory reset". Use at your own risk, and it can be easily changed on a rooted phone

Comment: But we can set constraint for null values , there will be no risk i guess for rooted devices too

Comment: if we are making ANDROID_ID as primary key than same user can make more than one account from one device this is only risk :)

Comment: Yea true , thank you for information means we can not overcome this problem right !! for rooted devices

Comment: No friend you can use other technique for this i have use in my project that you can see this https://gist.github.com/milaptank/25eddae25b59c643eb19 :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll use too whenever require

Answer (score 1):

If the ID doesn't need to be regeneratable (e.g. when the user signs in from the new phone) then just use a [UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html).

It will be based on the current time and the Hardware ID of the network adapter (wifi)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Java 5 there is a UUID (Unique identifier) class. So just do something like this:

```
UUID userId = UUID.randomUUID();
```

And you will have a Unique ID for that session that you can store.

Comment: If you actually check out the post time, they were published at the exact same moment.